# Firebase: Runing transaction every time I loop through an Array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to loop through Array and run transaction to upload each item on Firebase, but am not sure that what i want to do is possible.

The idea is: I have an Array of problems `["problemType1", "problemType2", ... "problemType10"]` and I give the user `n` time to solve it. At the end, I put the solved problems in Array and upload them on Firebase. If the problem exists in the DB, just to update his value.

This way, I want to track what type of problems the player use to resolves easier. At the moment, the code I wrote uploads only one problem. What am I doing wrong?

```
func uploadTheResolvedProblemsToDB(problems: [String], uid: String) {

let refDB = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("problems")

for problem in problems {

    refDB.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData:FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in

        var dataToUpdate = currentData.value as? [String : Any]

        if dataToUpdate?[problem] == nil {
            dataToUpdate = [problem: 0]
            var theProblem = dataToUpdate?[problem] as? Int ?? 0
            theProblem += 1
            dataToUpdate?[problem] = 1
            currentData.value = dataToUpdate
            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }
        else
        {
            var theProblem = dataToUpdate?[problem] as? Int ?? 0
            theProblem += 1
            dataToUpdate?[problem] = theProblem
            currentData.value = dataToUpdate
            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }
        }) {(error,commited,snapshot) in
        if let error = error {
            print("errorrrrr", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
}
```

My Database structure is:

```
users
    I_uid
         I_problems
                   I_problem1: 1
                     problem2: 1
                     problem3: 1
```

Where `problems` is the child. `problem1`, `problem2`, `problem3` are the values and `1` is the number of times resolved, each problem was resolved.

Comment: Try refDB.child(problem.uid).runTransactionBlock.

Comment: my db structure is - refdb.child(problems) i want it as flat as possible. i'll update the question.

Comment: Is it might relevant to this line: `dataToUpdate?[problem] = 1`? I haven't tested any code, it just seems odd you are hardcoding it to 1 since you can just set it to `theProblem` just like below.

Comment: thanks i removed it, i'm recicling code from another solution and there were more childs to update, this is what remained and i didn't noticed it. still, it's not relevant to the issue, but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still think the problem's your reference.

```
func uploadTheResolvedProblemsToDB(problems: [String], uid: String) {
  let refDB = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("problems")
  for problem in problems {
    refDB.child(problem).runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
      var value = currentData.value as? Int
      if value == nil {
        value = 1
      } else {
        value += 1
      }
      currentData.value = value
      return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
    }) { (error, comited, snapshot) in
         if let error = error {
           print("errorrrrr", error.localizedDescription)
         }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this way it gives me a different child for every problem, but i want to keep one child and update only the values.

Comment: But your structure says you have I_problem1, I_problem2, I_problem3 under problems? That's what this does.

Comment: my bad, it's only one child and there below are the values

Comment: sorry, i thought it's obvious that the child is "problems" i'll edit the post once again ;)

Comment: Either I'm just derping really hard or I'm still 100% sure this code does exactly what you want. Have you tried it?

Comment: haha, sure, it works, but if there are 3 problems, it updates only 1.

Comment: it's exactly what i want, but in my DB it updates only the first of the problems. hmm ...

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your logic a little bit but I believe this is how it should work instead. I have not ran a Firebase instance on this so if there are some discrepancies, its because I cannot fully test it. I hope it helps though:

```
let refDB = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("problems")

for problem in problems {
    refDB.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData:FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in

        var dataToUpdate = currentData.value as? [[String : Any]]

        if var resultData = dataToUpdate {
            if dataToUpdate.keys.contains(problem) {
                if let timesResolved = dataToUpdate[problem] as? Int {
                    resultData[problem] = timesResolved + 1
                }
                else {
                    resultData[problem] = 0
                }
            }
            else {
                resultData[problem] = 0
            }

            if !resultData.keys.contains(problem) {
                resultData[problem] = dataToUpdate[problem] ?? 0
            }

            currentData.value = resultData
            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }
    }) {(error,commited,snapshot) in
        if let error = error {
            print("errorrrrr", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: seems what i was looking for, i'll give it a try.

Comment: sorry but the other answer seems to works fine, and since it was first, i just marked it like an answer. still i think your answer deserves +1 too. thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)